# Redeclare class with same name in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

In example, I have parent class:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, param = False):
        somecode
```

I want redeclare class Test with same name Test to change default value of param:

```
class Test(Test):
    def __init__(self, param = True):
        super().__init__(param)
```

Is this a normal idea or is it wrong to do that?

Comment: Why you want to re-declare a class with same name?

Comment: I wrote the code and realized that I needed to change the default parameter. I do not want to replace the name already used in all the code.